# If a hypersurface has a self-intersection point, then the second fundamental form it is negative in a neighborhood of this point

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I'm studying by myself Mean Curvature Flow and I'm reading Lecture Notes on Mean Curvature Flow by Xi-Ping Zhu. The doubt of the title of this topic arised when I read the proof of the following result:

> $\textbf{Corollary 2.7 (Preserving convexity)}$
>
> Let $X(\cdot, t)$ be a solution of the mean curvature flow. Suppose the initial hypersurface $X(\cdot,0)$ is a convex and compact hypersurface, then $X(\cdot,t)$ is also a convex and compact hypersurface for $t > 0$.
>
> $\textbf{Proof.}$ Applying the strong maximum principle, we know that $H(\cdot, t) > 0$ for $t > 0$. Combining Proposition $2.6$, we deduce that the second fundamental form of $X(\cdot, t)$ is positive definite for $t > 0$. To show $X(\cdot, t)$ remains embedded, we argue by contradiction. Suppose for some first time $t_0 > 0$ the solution $X(\cdot, t)$ develops a self-intersection. Clearly, at this self-intersection point, there must be a piece of hypersurface which has negative second fundamental form. This contradicts with the fact the second fundamental form of $X(\cdot, t)$ is positive definite everywhere for $t > 0$. $\square$

I didn't understand this part:

> Clearly, at this self-intersection point, there must be a piece of hypersurface which has negative second fundamental form.

It seems to be a well-known result, but I didn't find this result. Can anyone indicate a reference for this result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For sure this is a property of mean curvature flow (and not hypersurfaces). I guess one wants to argue that two points on the surface can only flow towards an intersection if there's negative curvature (ie in the presence of positive curvature, sufficiently nearby points should flow away from one another). I don't have anything useful to add about why this is true though.

Comment: Or maybe it has to do with a the fact that if the hypersurface is everywhere convex, then it cannot lie on both sides of a tangent plane at a fixed point. The contradiction is being couched in terms of saying that the latter can happen only if the second fundamental form is indefinite [why does the author say *negative*? this seems totally wrong].